# js get result of 2 or more numbers with mathematical expressions

Tags: javascript, math

I have a counting-Discord bot which works perfectly fine, but i want to add some specials. Users should can use mathematical expressions like +;-;/;*, but i can't get the result of the string

example:
`console.log(+"14+2")` or `console.log(Number.parseInt(+"1+3*5-1"))`
all equals NaN or just the first number.

i just found on another stackoverflow question how i can if it's a number like true and false, but not the result.

Comment: You could use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but it's very dangerous as you'll be executing untrusted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `math.js`:

```js
console.log(math.evaluate("14+2"))
console.log(math.evaluate("1+3*5-1"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/11.0.1/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very cool.  Didn't know math had an evaluate.  Is it safe?

Comment: Seems to be secure enough from the [docs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/security.html).

Comment: So, what's the difference between this and `eval()`? Seems like you'd be allowing evaluation of unescaped user input, which is exactly the dangerous part of `eval()`. https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/security.html

Answer (score 0):

You're adding strings and expecting a number result. You can't convert a string like "14 + 2" into an expression.

The methods you've described are valid, but they can only convert a string into a number, not a complete expression.

So, you can do something like this:

```
const result = Number("14") + Number ("2");
```

Which is effectively the same as this:

```
const result = +"14" + +"2"
```

Or this:

```
const result = Number.parseInt("14") + Number.parseInt("2")
```

But I think that the `Number()` method is a little more readable than either.

To get your input into the correct syntax, you may need to use something like [string.Split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)